# Java home in etc/enviroment in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-server

Cannot set `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/enviroment`  with `JAVA_HOME="/home/syncsys/bin/jdk1.7.0_10/"`

The command `echo $JAVA_HOME` gives me `/home/syncsys/bin/jdk1.7.0_10/` but it's not a correct Java HOME or I need something else?

**I dont want bashrc or profile (some issues)**. Only `/etc/enviroment` and a way to eliminate the need of reboot after `/etc/enviroment` updates.

**My /etc/envirment :**

```
JAVA_HOME="/home/syncsys/bin/jdk1.7.0_10"
PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

**some commands to test :**

```
syncsys@sync-pc:~$ JAVA_HOME=/home/syncsys/bin/jdk1.7.0_10
syncsys@sync-pc:~$ export JAVA_HOME
syncsys@sync-pc:~$ PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH
syncsys@sync-pc:~$ export PATH
syncsys@sync-pc:~$ java -version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.7-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
```

**update :**

```
$ cat /etc/environment 
JAVA_HOME="/home/syncsys/bin/jdk1.7.0_10"
PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
syncsys@sync-pc:~$ java -version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
```

**--------(solved) -------- Working sample that is now ok for me.**

```
 $ cat /etc/environment JAVA_HOME="/home/syncsys/bin/jdk1.7.0_10" PATH="/home/syncsys/bin/jdk1.7.0_10/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin‌​:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

I have read a lot of tutorials and similar forum posts for this but it's not working.

Comment: Remove slash at the end of the path.

Comment: ok. and how to eliminate the need to restart again and again after /etc/enviroment updations

Comment: did you make copy paste mistake in your question? the java-home you set and the echo cmd gave you are exactly same....

Comment: restart again and again it so unpleasant to make a system changes in the inappropriate manner.

Comment: I always knew that unix systems not for the ordinal home users why do they use it?

Comment: what I don't understand why do you put the java on the path if you set up java home?

Comment: do you have trouble in locating java?

Comment: @RomanC no. its in my /home. (and it doesnt matter where ever its located)

Comment: What's the matter with it, remove it from PATH.

Comment: this works $ cat /etc/environment JAVA_HOME="/home/syncsys/bin/jdk1.7.0_10" PATH="/home/syncsys/bin/jdk1.7.0_10/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin‌​:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

aha! I see the problem...

your JAVA_HOME is correct (if the path is pointing to your JDK, I hope so). The problem is you should change

```
PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH
```

into

```
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

because the executable file "java" is not in your JAVA_HOME, it sits in JAVA_HOME/bin

Comment: yes. i suspect that so. but my /etc/enviroment already has PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:"
            so what should i do?

Comment: $ cat /etc/environment 
JAVA_HOME="/home/syncsys/bin/jdk1.7.0_10"
PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
syncsys@sync-pc:~$ java -version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:

Comment: That was a typo in my answer. I fixed it.

Comment: this works $ cat /etc/environment 
JAVA_HOME="/home/syncsys/bin/jdk1.7.0_10"
PATH="/home/syncsys/bin/jdk1.7.0_10/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I said, pretty much: java bin in path before the rest of the path, except I said it before Kent did.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a progam called "galternatives" that will give you a visual representation of your alternatives symlinks to your java binaries.

Of course, you could probably set the JAVA_HOME separately (as an override) in a shell script like so:

```
JAVA_HOME=/any/location/i/want
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

Comment: Doesnt works ` $ JAVA_HOME=/home/syncsys/bin/jdk1.7.0_10
syncsys@sync-pc:~$ export JAVA_HOME
syncsys@sync-pc:~$ PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH
syncsys@sync-pc:~$ export PATH
syncsys@sync-pc:~$ java -version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.7-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless`

Comment: this works $ cat /etc/environment JAVA_HOME="/home/syncsys/bin/jdk1.7.0_10" PATH="/home/syncsys/bin/jdk1.7.0_10/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin‌​:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

Answer (score 0):

Try in your shell:

export JAVA_HOME=/etc/environment

if working, edit your .bash_profile file and add this line again for every session

Comment: this works $ cat /etc/environment JAVA_HOME="/home/syncsys/bin/jdk1.7.0_10" PATH="/home/syncsys/bin/jdk1.7.0_10/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin‌​:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this is my solution:

```
$] uname -a

Linux ******* x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

=> downloading a bin :jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
=> In my installation location

```
$]chmod u+x jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
$]./jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
...
Done

$]cd jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin
$]./java -version

java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
```

It works..

1/ check your server configuration
2/ verify the owner of diretories after unpackaging.
2/ use binary pacquage .bin

Regards.

Richy.